# Random data from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, random

I am doing a project where I need to randomly select data from mysql.The mysql database consists of a set of questions(say 100).I want to randomly select 20 questions from those 100.I need to be able to get the id(primary key) of that question too.I need the primary key so that the questions that get selected need to be hidden.So for example if I 20 questions are selected randomly those 20 get hidden and next time only 80 questions remain for the next selection.I have kept a display column,right now each question has a dispay value of 1,so when a questin gets selected i want those 20 to get a display value of 0.So is it possible on using mysql.I tried with java but wasnt able to get the primary key.I had used collection shuffle function for getting random functions.
Please help.

Comment: What scripting languages have you available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you use ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20, you'll get 20 random rows. Full query would look something like

```
SELECT id FROM questions 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: I need to extract these questions and display them on pdf using itext.So this should work right?I will be writing this in JSP.

Comment: This approach is very simple, but will not scale well.

Comment: The above query works fine.I just tried it.But now I need to change the value of display to 0.So just working on that now.